# Query from different database, Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to do this, different database:

```
var IDs =  (from a in db1.Table1 
            join b in db1.Table2 on a.Id equals b.Id 
            orderby a.Status 
            where b.Id == 1 && a.Status == "new" 
            select new Company { a.Id }).ToList();

var query = (from c in db2.Company
            join a in IDs on c.Id equals a.Id
            select new Company { Id = a.Id, CompanyId = c.CompanyId }).OrderByDescending(z => z.CompanyId).ToList();
```

I got this:

```
Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'M.Models.Company'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

**I think it is because of the ToList() at the second query.**

Comment: i think it is because you used anonymous types in query.

Comment: That's because you join with (I assume) in-memory list named `IDs`. You cannot join database table with in-memory list this way.

Comment: The anonymous type is unrelated there, I suspected `IDs` variable contains in-memory `List` which cannot be joined in second query.

Comment: If I remove .OrderByDescending(z => z.CompanyId).ToList() from the second query it works.

Comment: @Alvin well... what is `z.CompanyId` ? Could you try moving the order-by *before* the projection?

Comment: I update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely issue here is that the 2nd query has no good way of representing that *as a join*. I suspect your best option would be to switch to `Contains`:

```
var IDs =  (from a in db1.Table1 
            join b in db1.Table2 on a.Id equals b.Id 
            where b.Id == 1 && a.Status == "new" 
            select a.Id).Distinct().ToList();

var query = (from c in db2.Company
            where IDs.Contains(c.Id)
            select new { Id = a.Id, CompanyId = c.CompanyId }
         ).OrderByDescending(z => z.CompanyId).ToList();
```

This isn't ideal, and it will struggle for large lists, but it is at least a simpler pattern to represent into a parameterized query.

Comment: 2nd query not able to get id from IDs list